# init taking more arguments than were defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the error

> **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

whenever I run the code below. I have googled the problem but it seems like most people who encounter this error due so when they try to pass an object. I am simply trying to pass a string. Could someone help me out please?

```
class pigLatin_class(object):
    def __init__(self,sentence):
        self.sentence=sentence
    def pigLatinConverter(sentence):
        VOWELS=["a","e","i","o","u"]
        sentence=sentence.split()
        Pigword=""
        for word in sentence:
            if VOWELS[0] or VOWELS[1] or VOWELS[2] or VOWELS[3] or VOWELS[4] not in word:
                Pigword+=word[1:] + word[0] + "way" + " "
            elif word[0] in VOWELS:
                Pigword+=word + "hay" + " "
            else:
                for i in range(len(word)):
                    if word[i] in VOWELS:
                        Pigword+=word[i:] + word[0:i] + "ay" + " "
                        break
        return Pigword

p=pigLatin_class("ataruk esteban")
print(p)
```

---

UPDATE:
Fixed that problem, thanks to a comment.  Now, I get

```
<__main__.pigLatin_class object at 0x7f...>
```

Comment: Running the given code in both Python 2 and Python 3 does not give me an error; I just get `<__main__.pigLatin_class object at 0x7f500d9bce48>`.  Is this all of your code?  You need to show us enough so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: that is all the code, I get that as well when I run it in command prompt but the spyder IDE gives me the positional errors

Comment: Cannot reproduce on QPython3.

Comment: @Doe22 Try cleaning the IDE cache. Never used Spyder, so I don't know how you do it, but every IDE I've used has a "clean" task that often resolves cache problems.

Comment: I bet this isn't the code you're actually running. Is the file saved? Are you running the file you think you are?

Comment: There is another problem with your code though that came up when I tried the other method. You need to have `self` as the first parameter of `pigLatinConverter`, and don't pass in `sentence` since you already did to the constructor. Running it now, you'll get an error that `pigLatin_class` doesn't have a `split ` method, since `sentance` is the implicitly passed `pigLatin_class` Object.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, I have managed to get rid of the error, but I am now getting <__main__.pigLatin_class object at 0x7f500d9bce48> do you know why my code isn't working as intended?

Comment: @Doe22 That's the string representation of the object. You need to call `pigLatinConverter` inside the `print`. Note the comment I just posted above though, as that method is currently broken.

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry I think I have done what you told me to do but I still can't get it to work, can you please advise? edited code https://pastebin.com/H3Kfv9vF

Comment: @Doe22 Again, youneed to call `pigLatinConverter`. All your code does right now is create the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You printed the *object*, which is a Python handle.  If you want to see the result of the conversion, you now need

```
print(p.pigLatinConverter())
```

When you created the object, the text you supplied got stored in the **sentence** attribute.  However, that object includes a lot of other information, including references to its two methods (**__init__** and the converter).  Even such a simple object is somewhat complex, so we're very careful with how we refer to the parts we want at any given point.

You will also need to alter the references in your converter, like so:

```
def pigLatinConverter(self):
    VOWELS=["a","e","i","o","u"]
    sentence=self.sentence.split()
```

Note that *every* class method should have the calling object as the first parameter (traditionally called **self** in Python; it's **this** in some other languages).  Now, you *already* have the sentence stored in the calling object.

With these two changes, I now get output from your program:

```
> p=pigLatin_class("ataruk esteban")
> print(p.pigLatinConverter())

tarukaway stebaneway
```

Comment: Thanks.  Slow terminal response, and I didn't notice that I'd backed over the two missing chars.

Comment: ah yes thanks, that was a silly error on my part

Comment: @Doe22 You should upvote and accept the answer if it answered your question.